# Why does the Foreach doesn't impact?

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach, observablecollection

The code below doing a simple thing. manipulate the API's raw data and bind it to the view model's property.

I fetch data from a web service and save it to a object named calljsonObject. This is the raw data. Then I do a foreach loop to select the selected data from the raw data, and save it to a object named  tmpList, and at the last line, bind tmpList to the view model property named docList

```
           SingleBoardListRawData calljsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleBoardListRawData>(callbackjsonstring);

           ObservableCollection<SinglePostViewModel> tmpList = new ObservableCollection<SinglePostViewModel>();
           SinglePostViewModel tmpPost = new SinglePostViewModel();
           foreach (List<object> item in calljsonObject.data)
           {
               tmpPost.doc_id = (long)item[0];
               tmpPost.doc_title = (string)item[1];
               tmpPost.doc_author = (string)item[2];
               tmpPost.repliesCount = (long)item[4];
               tmpPost.doc_post_date = DateTime.Parse((string)item[5]);
               tmpPost.OnTop = (long)item[6];
               tmpPost.CoolPost = (long)item[7];
               tmpPost.doc_update_date = DateTime.Parse((string)item[9]);
               tmpPost.PicInDoc = (long)item[10];
               tmpPost.reply_user_name = (string)item[11];
               tmpPost.doc_brief = (string)item[13];
               tmpList.Add(tmpPost);
           }
           this.docList = tmpList;
```

But the result is the tmpList full of the same data, which is the result of the last foreach manipulation. But I thought that I've re-assigned the tmpPost value, it seems every Add method will take place the previous one.

I don't want to new a object everytime I do a foreach loop, I think it cost a lot,

My Question is :
1. Why?
2. How to solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're adding a reference to the same object on each iteration, and overwriting the data within that object on each iteration. You *need* to create a new object on each iteration. Move this line:

```
SinglePostViewModel tmpPost = new SinglePostViewModel();
```

into the loop.

```
foreach (List<object> item in calljsonObject.data)
{
    SinglePostViewModel tmpPost = new SinglePostViewModel();
    tmpPost.doc_id = (long)item[0];
    ...
}
```

> I don't want to new a object everytime I do a foreach loop, I think it cost a lot,

How do you expect to maintain the different values if you don't create that many objects? Where do you expect the data to live? And what evidence do you have for your performance concern?

It's very important that you understand how reference types and value types work. Please read [my article on this topic](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) and think about how that applies in your situation.

Comment: Is there any better way? doesn't it cost a lot when doing a NEW action everytime I loop?

Comment: @AlbertGao no, it really doesn't; allocations are cheap; collecting short-lived objects is cheap

Comment: @AlbertGao: No, it doesn't cost a lot (and in comparison with calling a web service, it's virtually free!) and no, there isn't a better way. You should really think about why you *expected* to be able to store lots of different values without creating lots of different objects. Where did you expect that data to be stored? There's a really important fundamental point to think about here.

Comment: I get it, thanks, the performance issue is just a newbie's thought =.=

Comment: @AlbertGao You are going to write down 10 pages of text. How many pieces of paper will you use—1 or 10? Are you going to write all text page by page on the same piece of paper for the sake of “saving” the other nine?

Comment: Wondering why do newbies worry about performance always at the first place…

Comment: @AlbertGao: Performance is important, but correctness is *more* important... and you really need to understand your code well before you can start doing any sort of optimization. When you understand what your code does, you can *then* start to work out what's expensive and in what context.

Comment: @OndrejTucny You were a newbie too at some point in the past, surely you can ask your past self? ;)

Comment: @Nolonar That's 20 years ago; different circumstances, different methods, different languages, different priorities etc. I was always taught to write *good* software at the first place instead of writing *fast* software ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that `SinglePostViewModel`, then you are adding the same reference multiple times in the list. There is only one instance of the `SinglePostViewModel` - you are simply over-writing it each time, hence the fail.

> I don't want to new a object everytime I do a foreach loop, I think it cost a lot

Unless you are talking 10s of millions of records, your concerns are very unlikely to be justified. The data needs to go *somewhere*, after all.

> My Question is : 1. Why? 2. How to solve it?

1. because you only have one object that you keep over-writing
2. don't do that